# URL to filesystem mapping in Apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, mod-rewrite

I have a blog which is at `mysite.tld/blog`. Currently `mysite.tld` redirects to `mysite.tld/blog` via an `index.php` in the root. Apparently when I set this up two years back I could not get the `.httaccess` file which is also in the root to work. On the filesystem, my blog is at `/var/www/blog`.

Now I create a simple website that I'd like to have show up at `mysite.tld`. It works via a PHP microframework which serves pages via an `index.php` file. I have this site in a git repo, and in this repo the `index.php` is located at `www/index.php`. I'd like to just have a clone of the repo on my server so I can just pull to update to a new version. So assuming I clone it as `site` in `/var/www`, the entry point ends up at `/var/www/site/www/index.php`.

I've spend the last 3 hours attempting to get this incredibly simple thing to work, to no avail. All I want to do is map URL `/blog` to `/var/www/blog` and the remainder of URL `/` to `/var/www/site/index`. What is the magical configuration I need for this?

Here is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Here is the output of `apache2ctl -V`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:27
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Here is the output of `apache2ctl -M`:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All I want to do is map URL `/blog` to `/var/www/blog` and the
>   remainder of URL `/` to `/var/www/site/index`. What is the magical
>   configuration I need for this?

You can easily do this with [Apache’s `Alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) like this. Note that I see you are using Apache 2.4.7 which might have a slightly different syntax than Apache 2.2 and earlier which this advice is based on. But that said, while the syntax might be slightly different but the overall concepts are still the same and I am fairly confident Apache 2.4 still has `Alias` functionality.

These items would be set in your main site’s Apache configuration file which would be in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. Now they might be in a file named `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` or in a separate file for the hostname like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.tld` so be sure to check your config before radically modifying the files.

This would set all requests to `http://mysite.tld/blog` to get content from `/var/www/blog`:

```
Alias /blog /var/www/blog
```

This would set all requests to `http://mysite.tld/` to get content from `/var/www/site/index`:

```
Alias / /var/www/site/index
```

Now that said, you might only need the `Alias /blog /var/www/blog`; that second `Alias / /var/www/site/index` might not be needed as long as your `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/site/index`.

A good, simple and concise overview of how Apache config setups work [can be found on this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps).